# assiging text to the correct button without switch statement

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-8

am developing an app for windows phone 8.0 in VS2012 in C#

my code works fine , but it's too long and i think there is a string format to do the same in 1 line of code
the problem is that i don't know how to do that

example :  i need to assign the button content text string to a the correct TextBlock by the the name of the button ( btn2 --> t2 , btn3 --> t3)

**There are 8 Buttons (btn1...btn8) and 8 TextBlocks (t1.....t8)**

So i have this code and it works :

```
private void LetterClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        switch (lettersTyped)
                {
                    case 1:
                        t1.Text = btn.Content.ToString();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        t2.Text = btn.Content.ToString();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        t3.Text = btn.Content.ToString();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        t4.Text = btn.Content.ToString();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        t5.Text = btn.Content.ToString();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        t6.Text = btn.Content.ToString();
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        t7.Text = btn.Content.ToString();
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        t8.Text = btn.Content.ToString();
                        break;
                }
    }
```

I want other method that doesn't use the switch statement

like  : `t"The code determines the number".Text = btn.Content.ToString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a `Dictionary<int, TextBlock>` with your letter count and the control that must be changed and just reference the number of letters typed:

```
dic[lettersTyped].Text = btn.Content.ToString();
```

You can initialize your directory by parsing the text blocks ids if you don't want to initialize all blocks by hand. However I don't see any way for you to do it in one line (unless it's a v. long line)

Pseudocode:

- find all relevant textblocks (e.g all text blocks with id in the form textxxx with xxx numerical)
- extract the numerical part of the id for each text block tb
- add an entry in the dictionary with key xxx and value control tb
- dereference correct textblock with dictionary[keys typed]

Comment: i didn't mean seriously 1 line , but not as many as switch statement

Comment: Then the dictionary with initialisation should be a good way, i'm adding pseudocode right now

Comment: I did that , while initializing the `Keys` (int) are all okay , but all the values are set to `null` although i assigned all the TextBlocks

Comment: Ops! i did it before the ` InitializeComponent();` 
my bad :)

Comment: Great! Now if you have plenty of text blocks don't forget to automatically register them to clean up init code

Answer (score 1):

Make a global (private/public/whatever) dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<Button, TextBox> dict;
```

Then initialize it somewhere (eg. the page's constructor) :

```
dict = new Dictionary<Button, TextBox>()
{
    { btn1, t1 },
    { btn2, t2 }
};
```

And finally you attach the same Click handler to all of the buttons:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    dict[btn].Text = btn.Text;
}
```

Sender is the Button you click, so you just take the text from it and attach it to the TextBox assigned to the Button in the Dictionary.
This way you don't need to juggle any list indexes.

Comment: this is wrong , where is `lettersTyped` ? 
it's what determines the number of the TextBlock , and who said anything about click event handlers?

Comment: @GabourX Uhm... you? Your `LetterClicked` method is pretty much the same thing.
And what exactly do you need that `lettersTyped` for? Each TextBox is assigned to a button by a dictionary pair.

Comment: `dict[btn]` is a `<Button,TextBox>` and it doesn't have `Text` property , therefore it wont be able to convert `string` to `object`

Comment: `dict[btn]` returns the value assigned in the dictionary to the `btn` key - in this case a TextBox object, which DOES have a Text property.

Answer (score 0):

you can add all textblock to a List and handle accordingly:

```
List <TextBlock> TBlocks=new List<TextBlock>();
TBlocks.Add(t1);
...
TBlocks.Add(t8);

private void LetterClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        TBlocks[lettersTyped-1].Text= btn.Content.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This look good , but when it gives me this error when i do `TBlocks.Add(t1);` :

Comment: invalid arguments , the context must be `List<TextBlock>.Add(TextBlock item)`

Answer (score 0):

If your `TextBlock`s are in one container, like `StackPanel`, for example:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="container">
    <TextBlock x:Name="t1" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="t2" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="t3" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="t4" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="t5" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="t6" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="t7" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="t8" />
</StackPanel>
```

Then you can get them by index.

```
TextBlock tb = container.Children[lettersTyped - 1] as TextBlock; // Convert lettersTyped to 0-based index
tb.Text = btn.Content.ToString();
```

Comment: When i do that  , all the TextBlock disappears , but the first one (tb1)

Comment: If i delete t1 , t2 shows itself , it look like it only shows the first object in the stack